# "java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out" AND "Socket.<init>(String, int) line: not available"

Tags: java, sockets, connection

I don't know what's wrong. I've created a server program and a client program, but client program is not working. I'm using a right host address and a constant port. I've even tried turning off my firewall and using IP string instead of host address.
Flowchart: I first run server in CMD which has an infinite loop, and then I run client in Eclipse. I tried running client in CMD too but it didn't work.

server code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {
    public static void main(String []args) throws IOException
    {
        int cont=1;
        Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
        ServerSocket srv = new ServerSocket(6017);
        System.out.print("Port = " + srv.getLocalPort() + "\n");
        Socket clientSocket = srv.accept();

        while(true)
        {
            clientSocket = srv.accept();
        }
    }
}
```

client code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import org.omg.CORBA.Request;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String []args) throws IOException
    {
        String hostName = "cpezg-94-253-139-28-cbl.xnet.hr";
        int portNumber = 6017;
        Socket socket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber); 

        System.out.print("Success!");
    }

}
```

Comment: General advice: always test your client-server apps on localhost first. When it works on localhost you can start testing it over any network including internet.

Comment: i am testing it on localhost, my own PC

Comment: Your `hostName` does not look like localhost...

Comment: The second line in your title is just part of the stack trace. It isn't a second error.

Comment: I'm connecting to my host as if its a different host, but thats my hostname.